# Calculate the minutes between to dates excluding evenings and weekends?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the business time between two dates, down to the minute. Business hours being defined as between 8 AM and 6 PM EST (or EDT if its daylight savings).

I've found this answer, which performs this in hours, but am unsure how to convert to minutes, and ensure my timezones wont be messed up:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092865/104998

```js
function isHoliday( /*Date*/ date) {
  for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
    if (holidays[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
 
  return false;
}

function diffHours( /*Date*/ d1, /*Date*/ d2) {
  var date1 = new Date(d1.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (d1.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + d1.getUTCDate() + " UTC");
  var date2 = new Date(d2.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (d2.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + d2.getUTCDate() + " UTC");

  var sum = 0;
  var oneday = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
  var hours, date;

  // first day
  if (!isHoliday(date1)) {
    // decrease by a whole day first (will be added later)
    sum -= 10;

    // add real hours
    hours = d1.getUTCHours() + d1.getUTCMinutes() / 60;
    if (hours <= 6) {
      sum += 10 - hours;
    } else if (hours <= 20) {
      sum += 4;
    } else {
      sum += 24 - hours;
    }
  }

  // last day
  if (!isHoliday(date2)) {
    // decrease by a whole day first (will be added later)
    sum -= 10;

    // add real hours
    hours = d2.getUTCHours() + d2.getUTCMinutes() / 60;
    if (hours <= 6) {
      sum += hours;
    } else if (hours <= 20) {
      sum += 6;
    } else {
      sum += hours - 14;
    }
  }

  // whole days
  while (date1 <= date2) {
    if (!isHoliday(date1)) {
      sum += 10;
    }

    // increase date by 1 day
    date1.setTime(date1.getTime() + oneday);
  }

  return Math.floor(sum);
}

// ==============
// examples below
// --------------

// array of Dates (in UTC) to skip
var holidays = [
  new Date("2012-01-04 UTC"),
];

for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
  console.log('holiday: ', holidays[i].toUTCString());
}

a = new Date("2012-01-01 12:00 UTC");
b = new Date("2012-01-02 12:00 UTC");
c = new Date("2012-01-02 22:00 UTC");
d = new Date("2012-01-03 07:00 UTC");
e = new Date("2012-01-05 12:00 UTC");

console.log({
  d1: a.toUTCString(),
  d2: b.toUTCString(),
  hours: diffHours(a, b)
});
console.log({
  d1: b.toUTCString(),
  d2: c.toUTCString(),
  hours: diffHours(b, c)
});
console.log({
  d1: c.toUTCString(),
  d2: d.toUTCString(),
  hours: diffHours(c, d)
});
console.log({
  d1: d.toUTCString(),
  d2: e.toUTCString(),
  hours: diffHours(d, e)
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To convert to minutes multiply hours by 60

Comment: Thanks for the tip George :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class I came up with to do this, there must be a better way (this is my first time delving into nodejs)

```js
var dateFuncs = DateFuncs.prototype;

function DateFuncs() {

}


DateFuncs.prototype.isWeekend = function(pDate) {
    return (pDate.getDay() == 0 || pDate.getDay() == 6);
}

DateFuncs.prototype.isBusinessMinute = function(pDate) {
    var hours = pDate.getHours() + pDate.getMinutes()/60;
    return (hours >= 8 && hours < 18); //business hours are 8AM-6PM
}

DateFuncs.prototype.addMinutes = function(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}

DateFuncs.prototype.diffBusinessMins = function(/*Date*/ startDate, /*Date*/ endDate) {
  var minutesDiff = 0;
  startDate.setSeconds(0,0);
  endDate.setSeconds(0,0);

  var curDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());

  while(curDate.getTime() != endDate.getTime())
  {
    if(!this.isWeekend(curDate) && this.isBusinessMinute(curDate))
    {
      minutesDiff += 1;
    }

    curDate = this.addMinutes(curDate, 1);
  }

  return minutesDiff;
}



module.exports = DateFuncs;
```